# How do I get data from an array in an object within an object from an api

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I created a simple weather app using the OpenWeatherMap API. The schema is as follows:

```json
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": -122.08,
    "lat": 37.39
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 282.55,
    "feels_like": 281.86,
    "temp_min": 280.37,
    "temp_max": 284.26,
    "pressure": 1023,
    "humidity": 100
  }...
```

I'm trying to access the values within the weather key which contains an array. This is what I tried:

```
let iconImage = '';
data.weather.map((description, icon) => {
   this.description.textContent += description;
   iconImage += icon;
});
this.icon.setAttribute('src', data.weather.icon);
```

The `description` and `icon` are variables that point to li elements in my html code where the data I get from the API is supposed to enter.

How do I do this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data = {
  "coord": {
    "lon": -122.08,
    "lat": 37.39
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 282.55,
    "feels_like": 281.86,
    "temp_min": 280.37,
    "temp_max": 284.26,
    "pressure": 1023,
    "humidity": 100
  }
};
console.log(data.weather[0].icon);
```

Comment: Worked for getting the description @Alessio Cantarella